# Weighted sparse categorical cross entropy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, image-segmentation, cross-entropy

I am dealing with a semantic segmentation problem where the two classes in which I am interested (in addition to background) are quiet unbalanced in the image pixels. I am actually using sparse categorical cross entropy as a loss, due to the way in which training masks are encoded. Is there any version of it which takes into account class weights? I have not been able to find it, and not even the original source code of sparse_categorical_cross_entropy. I never explored the tf source code before, but the link to source code from API page doesn't seem to link to a real implementation of the loss function.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/nlp/modeling/losses/weighted_sparse_categorical_crossentropy.py) could be adapted to work for segmentation. I'm to inexperienced with both python and keras to do such a thing. Maybe it already works(?) however, it has "dimension problems" when I pass it an array with class weights.

Answer (score 2):

I think [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/segmentation) is the solution to weigh `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` in Keras.
They use the following to add a "second mask" (containing the weights for each class of the mask image) to the dataset.

```
def add_sample_weights(image, label):
  # The weights for each class, with the constraint that:
  #     sum(class_weights) == 1.0
  class_weights = tf.constant([2.0, 2.0, 1.0])
  class_weights = class_weights/tf.reduce_sum(class_weights)

  # Create an image of `sample_weights` by using the label at each pixel as an 
  # index into the `class weights` .
  sample_weights = tf.gather(class_weights, indices=tf.cast(label, tf.int32))

  return image, label, sample_weights


train_dataset.map(add_sample_weights).element_spec
```

Then they just use `tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy` as loss function and fit like:

```
weighted_model.fit(
    train_dataset.map(add_sample_weights),
    epochs=1,
    steps_per_epoch=10)
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can use class weights in model.fit for any loss function. I have used it with categorical_cross_entropy and it works. It just weights the loss with the class weight so I see no reason it should not work with sparse_categorical_cross_entropy.

Comment: Using class_weight in fit it says `class_weight not supported for 3+ dimensional targets.`

Comment: Doesn't work for segmentation. They even have a ```weighted_sparse_categorical_crossentropy``` loss [on GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/nlp/modeling/losses/weighted_sparse_categorical_crossentropy.py). However, it won't work. ```tf.keras``` expects labels to be integer values, not segmentation masks.

Anyways, I just commented in the hope this question will be answered someday since I also desperately need this loss function for semantic segmentation.

Comment: Aparently sparse_categorical_crossentropy and weighted_categorical_crossentropy behave very differently under the hood. I have found that adding class_weights while using scce does not work as @Vitto pointed out

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Keras Sparse Categorical Crossentropy doesn't work with class weights. I have found [this](https://gist.github.com/jonnyli1125/5384bb9a41caaac983f1cd737359c6c2) implementation of sparse categorical cross-entropy loss for Keras, which is working to me. The implementation in the link had a little bug, which may be due to some version incompatibility, so I've fixed it.

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    from tensorflow import keras

    class WeightedSCCE(keras.losses.Loss):
        def __init__(self, class_weight, from_logits=False, name='weighted_scce'):
            if class_weight is None or all(v == 1. for v in class_weight):
                self.class_weight = None
            else:
                self.class_weight = tf.convert_to_tensor(class_weight,
                    dtype=tf.float32)
            self.name = name
            self.reduction = keras.losses.Reduction.NONE
            self.unreduced_scce = keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
                from_logits=from_logits, name=name,
                reduction=self.reduction)
    
        def __call__(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
            loss = self.unreduced_scce(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)
            if self.class_weight is not None:
                weight_mask = tf.gather(self.class_weight, y_true)
                loss = tf.math.multiply(loss, weight_mask)
            return loss
```

The loss should be called by taking as an argument the list or array of weights.